# How to select a noncontiguous region of arbitrary rows in a rectangle?

Tags: region, rectangle

I can use Rectangle commands (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html) to operate over a text region.

What if I want to select text from columns COL to COL+4 over different rows, i.e., to add or remove characters or spaces at the beginning of multiple lines?

I'm sure this has to be dead easy to achieve, but I couldn't find any reference anywhere.

Comment: Please clarify: Do you mean that the rows are not consecutive? How are the "multiple lines" to be selected? An example might help.

Comment: A "region" means a contiguous sequence of characters in the buffer, so your subject is confusing -- any normal selection is "an arbitrary region".  You then mention rectangles and "multiple lines", and rectangles *do* operate over "multiple lines", so this is also confusing.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: @phils: Actually, Emacs supports "noncontiguous regions" to some extent now. (That's the term the docs use - e.g., argument `REGION-NONCONTIGUOUS-P` for helper function `perform-replace` and functions that use it.)

Comment: @Drew: Ah, interesting.  I see that the `region-extract-function` variable can be bound, and it can return a *list* (edit: which I now see you've written an answer about).  The (old) rectangle commands I use are AFAIK all based on `apply-on-rectangle` (which doesn't use that approach), so I didn't know about this feature.  Neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs can not do it out of the box, rectangle commands operate on contiguous range.

But there are packages that might be what you need:

- Multiple cursors https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el
- iedit https://github.com/victorhge/iedit

and probably more.

Comment: Wonderful answer! Straight to the point, and extra helpful thanks to the provided links.

Answer (score 3):

> What if I want to select text from columns COL to COL+4 over different rows, i.e., to add or remove characters or spaces at the beginning of multiple lines?

Yes, what if you do? *How do you want to tell Emacs* which rows to use?

Emacs does let you create such a *noncontiguous* region. (It lets you create noncontiguous regions of any kind, not just those that fit nicely into a rectangle.)

But it's up to you to define a function (e.g., a command) that somehow gets from the user the info about which rows in a rectangle to keep (or alternatively, which rows not to keep). You assign or bind variable `region-extract-function` to your function.

---

Here's one way you can play with this - but if you're defining a feature for other users then you'll want to think about how you would have them tell you where the pieces of a noncontiguous region are, i.e., how to interactively split up a rectangular region into pieces that are not contiguous (which rows to leave out).

To get a feel for this, and as food for thought: you can leverage library [Zones](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Zones) ([`zones.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zones.el)). For example:

In a buffer where you haven't done any narrowing (or if you have, do `(setq zz-izones  nil)`):

1. For each piece of text you want to include in your noncontiguous region, in order (e.g. from top to bottom of your rectangle: select it, then hit **`C-x n a`**.

   That adds that zone of text to the value of the default zones variable, `zz-izones`.
2. Evaluate this code:

```lisp
   (setq orig-r-e-f               region-extract-function
         region-extract-function  #'foo)

   (defun foo (method)
     (if (eq method 'bounds)
         (zz-noncontiguous-region-from-izones)
       (funcall orig-r-e-f method)))
```

3. Use some Emacs command, such as `query-replace`, that can act on a noncontiguous region.

   (You probably need to activate the region first, e.g. with `C-SPC`, even though the region is ignored by the new value of `region-extract-function`. This is because commands such as `query-replace` only act on a noncontiguous region when they think the region is active.)
4. When done playing around, do `M-: (setq region-extract-function  orig-r-e-f)` to restore the original value of that variable.

In a real setting you would do a bit more, and more cleanly, but that gives you an idea. In a nutshell:

- `C-x n a` adds the current active region to the sequence of zones recorded as the value of variable `zz-izones`. (A sequence of zones is similar to a vanilla-Emacs noncontiguous region, but it's more general.)
- Function `zz-noncontiguous-region-from-izones` does just what it says: it takes the zones from variable `zz-izones` and returns a corresponding vanilla-Emacs noncontiguous region.
- If you set or bind variable `region-extract-function` to a function which, when passed the symbol `bounds`, returns a noncontiguous region, then you can pass that variable to various vanilla Emacs functions -- such as `perform-replace` -- that act on a noncontiguous region.

The reason I introduce you to `zones.el` here is that `C-x n a` gives you an easy interactive way to set up a sequence of zones, which give you a noncontiguous region.

Obviously, if the noncontiguous region that you want always has *rows of a rectangle*, then you could come up with another, simpler, way for a user to specify the region pieces. But at least `C-x n a` gives you an interactive way to do so directly.

Comment: TYVM Drew for your explanation, I now understand better how this functionality is handled in Emacs. Upvoted!

Comment: @solr: I added some more info, so you can play with it.